# SQL Server Script Component to connect and Make a Destination

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis, script-component

I hope I've added this to the right part of the forum - it's about SQL Server Visual Studio 2017 using a Script Component with a source table I've created and want to bring into the Project.

So, I have a SQL Server SSIS Project built in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 8 o/s.
I have connected an .xls file to the Script component (SC) and now want to add the script that I need to add to the below that will allow me to see the output in the destination file.

The fields in my table are `CustID`, `Person_ID`, `StoreID`.

I've created the Output files in the Input/Output part of the SC as well as the Connection manager.

Next I want to add the relevant code to see the output from the table - NOTE the output should be exactly the same as the source table.

I've found that I need to add  script to the Script after the AddRows() line

And then I would add the below;

```
MyOutputBuffer.AddRow();
//Below is where I'm stuck...
MyOutputBuffer.CustID = //"What should I add here to get the result from my table??"
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Based on my understanding, you're extract data from xls to falt file, so no need to use Script component, just mapping them with Data flow.

Answer (score 0):

To access the Inputs columns you have to use `Row.<Column name>` to read the column value. As example:

```
MyOutputBuffer.CustID = Row.CustID;
```

For more information you can refer to the following documentation:

- [Creating an Asynchronous Transformation with the Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-an-asynchronous-transformation-with-the-script-component?view=sql-server-2017)